# Underline the proof

Tags: formatting

I attached the code of my tex file. I am wondering how to underline the "Proof that 1+1=2." I think that proof environment should be added somehow.

Many thanks for your help!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,text={16.5cm,25.2cm},centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\onehalfspacing


\newmdtheoremenv{theo}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{theorem}[theo]{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{corollary}{Corollary}

\parskip 1em


\title{\textbf{1+1=2}}
\author{}
\date{}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\large


\begin{proof}[Proof that $1+1=2$] 

\end{proof}        



\end{document}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `\begin{proof}[\underline{Proof that $1+1=2$}]`? But do you really want underlining?

Comment: @egreg, I completely forgot about that simple possibility. Yeah I need that since I have multiple proofs inside big theorem and I want to emphasize where the proof starts and ends.